# Why doesn't my angular plunker work?

Tags: angularjs

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q7tjCFIKcx0tYWwN1p53?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <link data-require="qtip2@*" data-semver="2.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.0.0/jquery.qtip.min.css" />
    <link data-require="qtip2@*" data-semver="2.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.0.0/jquery.qtip.css" />
    <link data-require="qtip2@*" data-semver="2.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.0.0/basic/jquery.qtip.min.css" />
    <link data-require="qtip2@*" data-semver="2.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.0.0/basic/jquery.qtip.css" />
    <script data-require="qtip2@*" data-semver="2.0.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.0.0/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
    <script data-require="qtip2@*" data-semver="2.0.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.0.0/basic/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-contoller="mainController">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <test></test>
    {{1+1}}
  </body>
</html>
```

I am a new to angular so I just wanted to try it out on plunker. I wrote a simple angular directive , controller and module. The message `$scope` doesn't even appear with my main page all linked with `ngApp` and `ngController`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your question, but in the Plunker you posted, you need to add your module.js to load the angular app:

```
<script src="module.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Plunker, there are two missing pieces.

First you need to include jQuery (jQuery QTips is using it).

Second you need to include your `module.js`.

Updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sxDra1Mozo4ysnbCx701?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I viewed your code in plnkr and found that you are not even passing the value of $scope.message to your directive. Please correct this issue and you should see the message getting displayed. Thanks.